# Can we save the mount point in azure synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a question in Azure Synapse spark pool.
Does anyone know how to save the mount point? I did create the mount point referencing it to ADLS. It goes  deleted or not referenced once after session terminates.

I have used the same in Azure databricks, where we can create mount point once and use any number of times. I was looking at same kind of behavior in synapse as well.

```
mssparkutils.fs.mount( 
    "abfss://xyz@stadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RawData", 
    "/mountraw", 
    {"linkedService":"LS_ADLS_Raw"} 
)
```

appreciate if anyone answers this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-file-mount-api?wt.mc_id=azsynapseblog_nov2021_blog_azureeng#how-to-mount-gen2blob-storage

Comment: Thanks for responding, I did refer the same article to create mountpoint.. but it is getting out of reference once session is ended. My thinking is why should i execute mountpoint creation code in each execution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact solution for your requirement. This is possible in Databricks but not in Synapse.

As a workaround, you can use `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT` statement to export tables to files in Azure storage.

Refer: [CETAS with Synapse SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas?).

Comment: Thanks for the response, if MS wants build alternate to ADB , better to give certain feature which are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, this feature is not yet available on Azure Synapse Analytics. Our product team is currently working on this feature.

At this moment we don't have exact ETA on when will this feature will be available. And we will update this thread once it's available.